# Why does my single threaded hello world app use 22 OS threads?

Tags: java, jvm

Out of curiosity I wrote Hello World and set a break point on my print statement.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

When the break point was hit, I pulled up Task Manager in windows to see how many threads were allocated by that JVM process. I was shocked to see 22.  Why are there so many threads spawned for this simple program?

Comment: there are many deamon threads too. Like GC being one of them.

Comment: Have you stopped to look at their names? They are usually quite descriptive, even self-explanatory at times.

Comment: And don't forget that the debugger takes up a whole host of threads. And if you have JMX turned on, there's a whole lot more.

Comment: Wouldn't the debugger and the IDE also be included in that number?

Comment: Probably depends on your JVM implementation, but there's a lot of stuff that needs to happen.  A short list of things the JVM needs includes garbage collection threads, I/O threads, classloading threads, threads to deal with operating system calls, etc.  22 actually seems like a low number when you consider how much is going on.

Comment: @JasonSperske IDE no. But the debugger starts a server on the client side that the IDE will connect to - many threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Only five reported in my IDE. The usual suspects. GC, finalization, etc.

Comment: The one thread gets lonely and scared, having to face the entire world by itself.  The others are for moral support.

Comment: I provided the beginnings of an answer just in case anybody wants to, you know, answer the question :P

Comment: @austin Add JIT compiler's threads to that list... don't know how many though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ran outside of debugger, thread count still 19.

Comment: How did you get the thread count without a debugger?

Comment: @BoristheSpider From the OS.  I'm running Windows.  I can call up the Task Manager and inspect how many threads a process has allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, FYI, just discovered that the JVM will allocate at least *n* threads to GC where *n* is the number of cores.  Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.  That explains 8 of mine.

Answer (score 7):

The JVM utilizes some daemon thread (e.g. garbage collector, finalizer, etc...). However, in this case, attaching a debugger has actually created a few more threads to handle the debuggers connection.

Comment: Ran witout debugger (java -jar ... with a sleep call).  Still 19 threads.

Comment: austin gave a very good list of concern which have dedicated threads.

Comment: You've just discovered Java's enormous overhead. Congratulations.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I would have guessed 5-6.  I was surprised to see over 20.

Comment: @SevenBits I smell a flame war

Comment: @BoristheSpider That statement *is* accurate! however. All the Java fans should admit that at least.

Comment: @SevenBits Java hogs RAM, but I don't hear much complaints on the shortage of RAM. On the other hand, it is very careful with CPU time overheads---and that's where all the eyes are.

Answer (score 1):

As above says, there are many Daemon Threads runs always by JVM. To watch all your current running threads, open `Java VisualVM` in your `JDK-->bin` folder and go to Threads. There you can see all running, sleeping, wait and Monitor Threads.

Currently in my `VisualVM`, I have `19` Live Threads in which `15` are Daemon Threads.